# Arduino Programming adding milliseconds delay

Tags: c++, arduino

So I'm trying to create an energy meter device which will read power every minute and then send it every 5 minutes through a LoRa server, using an MKR 1300 arduino. The problem is that as of now the hardware is removing a few milliseconds on the delay and so the time in the server ends up being p.e:

10:50:30

10:50:30

10:50:30

... 2 hours later

10:50:29

10:50:29

...

10:49:59

The code looks like this:

```
#include <MKRWAN.h>
#include "EmonLib.h"
LoRaModem modem;

String appEui = "1234567891011121";
String appKey = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff";

EnergyMonitor emon1;
EnergyMonitor emon2;
EnergyMonitor emon3;

double totalWatt;
int time_running;
int sending;
int totalKW;
int DELAY = 60000; // millis

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (!modem.begin(EU868)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to start module");
    while (1) {}
  };
  Serial.print("Your module version is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.version());
  Serial.print("Your device EUI is: ");
  Serial.println(modem.deviceEUI());

  Serial.println("Connecting");
  int connected = modem.joinOTAA(appEui, appKey);
  if (!connected) {
    Serial.println("Something went wrong; are you indoor? Move near a window and retry");
    while (1) {}
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");

  modem.minPollInterval(60);

  analogReadResolution(9);
  emon1.current(1, 53);
  emon2.current(2, 53);
  emon3.current(3, 53);
  time_running = 0;

  randomSeed(analogRead(A4));

}

void loop() {
  unsigned long StartTime = millis();

  totalWatt = 0;
  unsigned long delay_send = 0;
  int sending = 0;

  double Irms1 = emon1.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms1 < 0.3) Irms1 = 0;
  double Watt1 = Irms1 * 230;

  double Irms2 = emon2.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms2 < 0.3) Irms2 = 0;
  double Watt2 = Irms2 * 230;

  double Irms3 = emon3.calcIrms(600);
  if (Irms3 < 0.3) Irms3 = 0;
  double Watt3 = Irms3 * 230;

  totalWatt = Watt1 + Watt2 + Watt3;
  totalKW = totalKW + totalWatt/1000;


  if (time_running == 5) { //15 para 15 mins
    double IrmsTotal = Irms1 +Irms2 + Irms3;
    String msg = "{\"id\":\"avac_aud1\",\"kW\":"+String(totalKW)+", \"current\":"+String(IrmsTotal)+"}";
    int err;
    modem.beginPacket();
    modem.print(msg);
    err = modem.endPacket(true);
    if (err > 0) { 
      //message sent correctly
      time_running = 0;
      totalKW = 0;
    } else {
      Serial.println("ERR");
      time_running = 0;
    }
  }

 time_running = time_running + 1;

 if ((millis() - StartTime) > DELAY){
    delay(10);
    return;
 } else{
    delay(DELAY-(millis() - StartTime));
    return;
 } 
}
```

I tried adding a variable ARD_DELAY (not shown above) to the code that in that last delay would subtract 7 to 8 milliseconds to try and fix this, but apparently, it only made it worse (now it removes 1 second every 1 hours instead of 2 hours) so today I'll try to add those 7 to 8 millis and see if it works, but I would really like to know why the heck this is happening because from what I can see from my code the delay should always account for the processed time including the data sending time.

Comment: Note that the usual way to deal with wall clock on such devices is to connect some kind of RTC device to it (eg: DS3231). The thing is, you don't know what the accuracy of the internal clock you get with `millis` is. Check this question: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/242/arduino-time-clock-accuracy

Comment: @spectras There is even 32.768kHz xtal on this board, so he just have to setup RTC (and eventually interrupts properly).

Comment: @KIIV Oh I had no idea RTC meant Real Time Clock (seriously new at these kind of things), do you have any tips on how to use the RTC library from Arduino to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/RTC - the simple alarm example might exactly fit your needs: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleRTCAlarm - as far as I see, you'd have to re-adjust alarm time to get next one within the callback.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah I've tried that library but apparently, for some reason, when I use both the RTC and the LoRa MKRWAN library to send data the data doesn't get sent and I have no idea why, because when I remove the RTC it work perfectly (to send)

Comment: I've added a new thread for the RTC issue, trying to figure out why this happens it might be a coding issue

Answer (score 2):

Question is, how precise is your clock at all...

Still, I personally would rather go with the following approach:

```
#define DELAY (5UL * 60UL * 1000UL) // or whatever is appropriate...

static unsigned long timestamp = millis();
if(millis() - timestamp > DELAY)
{
    // adding a fix constant will prevent accumulating deviations over time
    timestamp += DELAY;
    // run the every-5-min task...
}
```

*Edit: combined 1-min and 5-min task:*

Variant 1:

```
#define DELAY_SHORT (1UL * 60UL * 1000UL)
#define DELAY_LONG  (5UL * 60UL * 1000UL)

static unsigned long timestampS = millis();
static unsigned long timestampL = timestampS;
if(millis() - timestampS > DELAY_SHORT)
{
    timestamp += DELAY_SHORT;
    // run the every-1-min task...
}
if(millis() - timestampL > DELAY_LONG)
{
    timestamp += DELAY_LONG;
    // run the every-5-min task...
}
```

Variant 2:

```
#define DELAY_1M (1UL * 60UL * 1000UL)

static unsigned long timestamp = millis();
if(millis() - timestamp > DELAY)
{
    // adding a fix constant will prevent accumulating deviations over time
    timestamp += DELAY;
    // run the every-1-min task...

    static unsigned int counter = 0;
    if(++counter == 5)
    {
        counter = 0;
        // run the every-5-min task...
    }
}
```

Comment: how is that different from `delay(DELAY-(millis() - StartTime));`?

Comment: @Juraj You need to look at wider scope; I totally avoid busy waiting within the loop function. Just one single simple check: is the interval elapsed? Then do what is needed. Otherwise just go on. Total control to you, you don't rely on whatever `delay` function is doing - which *might* (or not) be the source of accumulating time deviations.

Comment: @Aconcagua Will also try this code, but I don't see where I would add my 1 minute loop that I need for each reading.

Comment: @BryceSoker You could either duplicate the code for each interval (each with its own timestamp variable; both `if`s *parallel*, not nested!) or check for 1min only and maintain a counter based on which you execute the 5min task then.

Comment: @Aconcagua This could work, but my problem here is that the data send normally takes 5 seconds but if there is an error it could go up to more than 10 seconds, so for each error, it would add 5 seconds or more which could screw this up. Either way, I got told that RTC is a thing in this board except that for some damn reason Lora and RTC apparently aren't working together, so in the off chance I can't do this I'll end up using this code. Thank you.

Comment: @BryceSoker Have a very close look: Let's say I take the initial timestamp at 77ms. Then as soon as 60000ms elaps (time will be 60077 then), action is taken. It does not matter at all how long your actions take, 10ms, 15ms, 1012ms (unless they last longer than 60000ms...), as there is 60000 added to 77 in `timestamp`, next interval elapses at - guess - 120077 - and so on. The secret is: I do solely check the interval being elapsed *and* I add *fixed* interval to timestamp again and again...

Comment: Oh so basically it's on an active loop? Good thing I will be connecting directly to the power source then. Also I heard somewhere that the millis can reset once it reaches a certain value, I hope that is not true, but I also think that it was a rumor since I can't find anything on it.

Comment: @BryceSoker It *is* true. At some point, millis will restart from 0. But that's not any trouble at all, as long as you *always* calculate *difference* between millis and timestamp: Imagine you only have 4 bits: 0, 1, 2, ... 14, 15,  0, 1, ...If your interval now is 4ms, then you get at some point e. g. timestamp = e, millis = 2. unsigned calculations use modulo arithmetics, you will have e. g. : `2 - e == 2 - e % 15 == 4`

Comment: Ah it's still going 1 second down every 2 hours added code and DB entry in you comment so to check if I did anything wrong.

Comment: @BryceSoker That might be a strong hint that *either* the clock on your arduino is running slightly too fast - *or* the clock you use for measureing running slightly too slow (or both effects combined). To be sure, you'd need to measure both now... But lets assume it is the MC running too fast. The number of ms in your DB *continuously* decreases (apart from the strange exception at 20:50 and the value for 22:20 missing). 1s in two hours, that's 8.33 ms every minute. Actually, if comparing ms, it rather seems that you are losing 1s in a bit more than every 135 min, i. e. 7.x ms every minute.

Comment: @BryceSoker So you might add these 7 ms to your time interval (`#define DELAY 60007UL` and perhaps every 5 minutes add another millisecond (`++timestamp;`), which will result in average of adding 7.2ms per minute. If you need more precision, you need to measure more precisely (which could mean over longer periods, like days).

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah that was the solution I was going to try too today but was trying to avoid since if I had one millisecond more it will start going up if I added one less it would keep going down, right now I will make it a random value between 7 and 8 every 1 minute and add it because sometimes it's not 27 entries but 24(120 mins) or 25(125).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to measure a start time and adding delay depending on that, you could keep track of the timing for your next cycle.

```
unsigned long next_cycle = DELAY;

...

void loop() {
    ...

    delay( next_cycle - millis() );
    next_cycle += DELAY;
}
```

If you also want to adjust for any time the program spends on initialization or similar, you can `next_cycle = millis() + DELAY;` before you enter your loop.

Comment: how is that different from `delay(DELAY-(millis() - StartTime));`?

Comment: @Juraj Let's say that after the call to `delay` and before the call to update `StartTime` 1ms passed. That 1ms would over time build up and after 1000 cycles, it would have pushed the cycle time to occur 1s later. This method eliminates the need to measure time before and keeps the cycle more even.

Comment: @super That's exactly what I thought, that the time between one loop and the other was adding another delay, and that's why i used the ARD_DELAY that would subtract 7 to 8 millis on the delay but it actually got worse. I'll still try this tho. Thanks.

Comment: so that would be the time arduino spent outside of loop. so the solution is to update the startTime after delay (and at the end of setup())

Comment: @Juraj Yes, that's also an option. But technically there could still be some amount of time "lost" before `StartTime` is updated in that case. This approach is in a sense more robust if the most important aspect is regular cycles.